# SQL Server 2016 Express installation error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016-express

I have two disks:

- (VeraCrypt-encrypted) HDD:  partition `A`
- SSD: partition `C`

Windows 10 Pro. Microsoft SQL Server Express 2016. I have changed from default partition `C` to `A`. I am getting this error when trying to install:

[image]

(For 2014 version It gives me the same error in `Installation progress` step).I changed to `C`, didn't help. I have changed to different directory (without `(x86)`), didn't help. I have checked online for similar questions but still can't figure it out. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Microsoft Windows Installer issue and is not related to Desktop Authority. In the registry of the workstation the value data for "Program Files (x86)" may contain invalid characters

You can read more about this problem and how to fix it in this [Article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ad7a1327-9700-4d71-8a67-f7aa9ed6bca6/sql-server-2008-r2-2008-r2-sp1-installation-fails-in-windows-server-2012?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: Thanks, it works. In my registry I had `D:\Program Files` and `D:\Program Files (x86)` - my mistake. How did you figure it out :), God Bless you. 2014 seems to be working fine (I will reinstall to an unecrypted partion if experience any troubles)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install it on an encrypted or compressed drive.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> SQL Server Setup will block installations on read-only, mapped, or
>   compressed drives.